# Different versions of Browsers or browser emulator

Tags: browser, cross-browser

I am developing a website in ASP.NET MVC, using the latest IE and Chrome for testing. It looks fine, but there are some quirks on older browsers like IE 6/7. Sadly, client base is rural, and I saw some people running IE 6 and 7 on their systems, this web site just doesn't look what it is.

Installing different versions and copying pasting an address 10-15 times is painful. I already have (all latest) Opera, Firefox, IE and Chrome. So, I am looking for emulating older browsers.

Is there any way, I can emulate browsers' different versions especially IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use http://browsershots.org/
This page creates screenshots in different browsers.

Comment: +1 good. but gives no hands on experience. but yes saves times. after initial quick look can go to specific browser for testing.

Comment: seems to be broken currently

Answer (score 16):

You can use [portable versions](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy) of Firefox to be able to run them simultaneously, as for IE you can use [IE Collections](http://finalbuilds.com/iecollection.htm) which contains different versions of IE :

> Utilu IE Collection contains the following versions of IE:
>
> - Internet Explorer 1.0 (4.40.308)
> - Internet Explorer 1.5 (0.1.0.10)
> - Internet Explorer 2.01 (2.01.046)
> - Internet Explorer 3.0 (3.0.1152)
> - Internet Explorer 3.01 (3.01.2723)
> - Internet Explorer 3.03 (3.03.2925)
> - Internet Explorer 4.01 (4.72.3110.0)
> - Internet Explorer 5.01 (5.00.3314.2100)
> - Internet Explorer 5.5 (5.51.4807.2300)
> - Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2800.1106)
> - Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2900.2180)
> - Internet Explorer 7.0 (7.00.5730.13)
> - Internet Explorer 8.0 (8.00.6001.18702)

Comment: this is a better answer for developing on a local dev site

Answer (score 2):

It looks like IE is the most problematic browser when using open standard so u can test using 
http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Internet-Explorer-Collection-Download-105889.html.